# strange segmentation fault during function return

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am running a program on 2 different machines. On one it works fine without issue. On the other it results in a segmentation fault. Through debugging, I have figured out where the fault occurs, but I can't figure out a logical reason for it to happen.

In one function I have the following code:

```
pass_particles(particle_grid, particle_properties, input_data, coll_eros_track, collision_number_part, world, grid_rank_lookup, grid_locations);
cout<<"done passing particles"<<endl;
```

The function pass_particles looks like:

```
void pass_particles(map<int,map<int,Particle> > & particle_grid, std::vector<Particle_props> & particle_properties, User_input& input_data, data_tracking & coll_eros_track, vector<int> & collision_number_part, mpi::communicator & world, std::map<int,int> & grid_rank_lookup, map<int,std::vector<double> > & grid_locations)
{
     //cout<<"east-west"<<endl;
    //east-west exchange (x direction)
    map<int, vector<Particle> > particles_to_be_sent_east;
    map<int, vector<Particle> > particles_to_be_sent_west;
    vector<Particle> particles_received_east;
    vector<Particle> particles_received_west;
    int counter_x_sent=0;
    int counter_x_received=0;
    for(grid_iter=particle_grid.begin();grid_iter!=particle_grid.end();grid_iter++)
    {
        map<int,Particle>::iterator part_iter;
        for (part_iter=grid_iter->second.begin();part_iter!=grid_iter->second.end();)
        {
            if (particle_properties[part_iter->second.global_part_num()].particle_in_box()[grid_iter->first])
            {
                //decide if a particle has left the box...need to consider whether particle was already outside the box 
                if ((part_iter->second.position().x()<(grid_locations[grid_iter->first][0]) && part_iter->second.position().x()>(grid_locations[grid_iter->first-input_data.z_numboxes()][0]))
                    || (input_data.periodic_walls_x() && (grid_iter->first-floor(grid_iter->first/(input_data.xz_numboxes()))*input_data.xz_numboxes()<input_data.z_numboxes()) && (part_iter->second.position().x()>(grid_locations[input_data.total_boxes()-1][0]))))
                {
                    particles_to_be_sent_west[grid_iter->first].push_back(part_iter->second);
                    particle_properties[particle_grid[grid_iter->first][part_iter->first].global_part_num()].particle_in_box()[grid_iter->first]=false;
                    counter_sent++;
                    counter_x_sent++;
                }

                else if ((part_iter->second.position().x()>(grid_locations[grid_iter->first][1]) && part_iter->second.position().x()<(grid_locations[grid_iter->first+input_data.z_numboxes()][1]))
                    || (input_data.periodic_walls_x() && (grid_iter->first-floor(grid_iter->first/(input_data.xz_numboxes()))*input_data.xz_numboxes())>input_data.xz_numboxes()-input_data.z_numboxes()-1) && (part_iter->second.position().x()<(grid_locations[0][1])))
                {
                    particles_to_be_sent_east[grid_iter->first].push_back(part_iter->second);
                    particle_properties[particle_grid[grid_iter->first][part_iter->first].global_part_num()].particle_in_box()[grid_iter->first]=false;
                    counter_sent++;
                    counter_x_sent++;
                }

                //select particles in overlap areas to send to neighboring cells
                else if ((part_iter->second.position().x()>(grid_locations[grid_iter->first][0]) && part_iter->second.position().x()<(grid_locations[grid_iter->first][0]+input_data.diam_large())))
                {
                    particles_to_be_sent_west[grid_iter->first].push_back(part_iter->second);
                    counter_sent++;
                    counter_x_sent++;
                }

                else if ((part_iter->second.position().x()<(grid_locations[grid_iter->first][1]) && part_iter->second.position().x()>(grid_locations[grid_iter->first][1]-input_data.diam_large())))
                {
                    particles_to_be_sent_east[grid_iter->first].push_back(part_iter->second);
                    counter_sent++;
                    counter_x_sent++;
                }
                ++part_iter;
            }
            else if (particles_received_current[grid_iter->first].find(part_iter->first)!=particles_received_current[grid_iter->first].end())
            {
                if ((part_iter->second.position().x()>(grid_locations[grid_iter->first][0]) && part_iter->second.position().x()<(grid_locations[grid_iter->first][0]+input_data.diam_large())))
                {
                    particles_to_be_sent_west[grid_iter->first].push_back(part_iter->second);
                    counter_sent++;
                    counter_x_sent++;
                }

                else if ((part_iter->second.position().x()<(grid_locations[grid_iter->first][1]) && part_iter->second.position().x()>(grid_locations[grid_iter->first][1]-input_data.diam_large())))
                {
                    particles_to_be_sent_east[grid_iter->first].push_back(part_iter->second);
                    counter_sent++;
                    counter_x_sent++;
                }
                part_iter++;
            }
            else
            {
                particle_grid[grid_iter->first].erase(part_iter++);
                counter_removed++;
            }
        }
    }

    world.barrier();

    mpi::request reqs_x_send[particles_to_be_sent_west.size()+particles_to_be_sent_east.size()];
    vector<multimap<int,int> > box_sent_x_info;
    box_sent_x_info.resize(world.size());
    vector<multimap<int,int> > box_received_x_info;
    box_received_x_info.resize(world.size());
    int counter_x_reqs=0;
    //send particles
    for(grid_iter_vec=particles_to_be_sent_west.begin();grid_iter_vec!=particles_to_be_sent_west.end();grid_iter_vec++)
    {
        if (grid_iter_vec->second.size()!=0)
        {
            //send a particle. 50 will be "west" tag
            if (input_data.periodic_walls_x() && (grid_iter_vec->first-floor(grid_iter_vec->first/(input_data.xz_numboxes()))*input_data.xz_numboxes()<input_data.z_numboxes()))
            {
                reqs_x_send[counter_x_reqs++]=world.isend(grid_rank_lookup[grid_iter_vec->first + input_data.z_numboxes()*(input_data.x_numboxes()-1)], grid_iter_vec->first + input_data.z_numboxes()*(input_data.x_numboxes()-1), particles_to_be_sent_west[grid_iter_vec->first]);
                box_sent_x_info[grid_rank_lookup[grid_iter_vec->first + input_data.z_numboxes()*(input_data.x_numboxes()-1)]].insert(pair<int,int>(world.rank(), grid_iter_vec->first + input_data.z_numboxes()*(input_data.x_numboxes()-1)));
            }
            else if (!(grid_iter_vec->first-floor(grid_iter_vec->first/(input_data.xz_numboxes()))*input_data.xz_numboxes()<input_data.z_numboxes()))
            {
                reqs_x_send[counter_x_reqs++]=world.isend(grid_rank_lookup[grid_iter_vec->first - input_data.z_numboxes()], grid_iter_vec->first - input_data.z_numboxes(), particles_to_be_sent_west[grid_iter_vec->first]);
                box_sent_x_info[grid_rank_lookup[grid_iter_vec->first - input_data.z_numboxes()]].insert(pair<int,int>(world.rank(),grid_iter_vec->first - input_data.z_numboxes()));
            }
        }
    }

    for(grid_iter_vec=particles_to_be_sent_east.begin();grid_iter_vec!=particles_to_be_sent_east.end();grid_iter_vec++)
    {
        if (grid_iter_vec->second.size()!=0)
        {
            //send a particle. 60 will be "east" tag
            if (input_data.periodic_walls_x() && (grid_iter_vec->first-floor(grid_iter_vec->first/(input_data.xz_numboxes())*input_data.xz_numboxes())>input_data.xz_numboxes()-input_data.z_numboxes()-1))
            {
                reqs_x_send[counter_x_reqs++]=world.isend(grid_rank_lookup[grid_iter_vec->first - input_data.z_numboxes()*(input_data.x_numboxes()-1)], 2000000000-(grid_iter_vec->first - input_data.z_numboxes()*(input_data.x_numboxes()-1)), particles_to_be_sent_east[grid_iter_vec->first]);
                box_sent_x_info[grid_rank_lookup[grid_iter_vec->first - input_data.z_numboxes()*(input_data.x_numboxes()-1)]].insert(pair<int,int>(world.rank(),2000000000-(grid_iter_vec->first - input_data.z_numboxes()*(input_data.x_numboxes()-1))));
            }
            else if (!(grid_iter_vec->first-floor(grid_iter_vec->first/(input_data.xz_numboxes())*input_data.xz_numboxes())>input_data.xz_numboxes()-input_data.z_numboxes()-1))
            {
                reqs_x_send[counter_x_reqs++]=world.isend(grid_rank_lookup[grid_iter_vec->first + input_data.z_numboxes()], 2000000000-(grid_iter_vec->first + input_data.z_numboxes()), particles_to_be_sent_east[grid_iter_vec->first]);
                box_sent_x_info[grid_rank_lookup[grid_iter_vec->first + input_data.z_numboxes()]].insert(pair<int,int>(world.rank(), 2000000000-(grid_iter_vec->first + input_data.z_numboxes())));
            }
        }
    }

    counter=0;
    for (int i=0;i<world.size();i++)
    {
        //if (world.rank()!=i)
        //{
            reqs[counter++]=world.isend(i,1000000000,box_sent_x_info[i]);
            reqs[counter++]=world.irecv(i,1000000000,box_received_x_info[i]);
        //}
    }

    mpi::wait_all(reqs, reqs + world.size()*2);

    //receive particles
    //receive west particles
    for (int j=0;j<world.size();j++)
    {
        multimap<int,int>::iterator received_info_iter;
        for (received_info_iter=box_received_x_info[j].begin();received_info_iter!=box_received_x_info[j].end();received_info_iter++)
        {
            //receive the message
            if (received_info_iter->second<1000000000)
            {
                //receive the message
                world.recv(received_info_iter->first,received_info_iter->second,particles_received_west);
                //loop through all the received particles and add them to the particle_grid for this processor
                for (unsigned int i=0;i<particles_received_west.size();i++)
                {
                    particle_grid[received_info_iter->second].insert(pair<int,Particle>(particles_received_west[i].global_part_num(),particles_received_west[i]));

                    if(particles_received_west[i].position().x()>grid_locations[received_info_iter->second][0] && particles_received_west[i].position().x()<grid_locations[received_info_iter->second][1])
                    {
                        particle_properties[particles_received_west[i].global_part_num()].particle_in_box()[received_info_iter->second]=true;

                    }
                    counter_received++;
                    counter_x_received++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //receive the message
                world.recv(received_info_iter->first,received_info_iter->second,particles_received_east);
                //loop through all the received particles and add them to the particle_grid for this processor
                for (unsigned int i=0;i<particles_received_east.size();i++)
                {
                    particle_grid[2000000000-received_info_iter->second].insert(pair<int,Particle>(particles_received_east[i].global_part_num(),particles_received_east[i]));
                    if(particles_received_east[i].position().x()>grid_locations[2000000000-received_info_iter->second][0] && particles_received_east[i].position().x()<grid_locations[2000000000-received_info_iter->second][1])
                    {
                        particle_properties[particles_received_east[i].global_part_num()].particle_in_box()[2000000000-received_info_iter->second]=true;

                    }
                    counter_received++;
                    counter_x_received++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    mpi::wait_all(reqs_y_send, reqs_y_send + particles_to_be_sent_bottom.size()+particles_to_be_sent_top.size());
    mpi::wait_all(reqs_z_send, reqs_z_send + particles_to_be_sent_south.size()+particles_to_be_sent_north.size());
    mpi::wait_all(reqs_x_send, reqs_x_send + particles_to_be_sent_west.size()+particles_to_be_sent_east.size());

    cout<<"x sent "<<counter_x_sent<<" and received "<<counter_x_received<<" from rank "<<world.rank()<<endl;

    cout<<"rank "<<world.rank()<<" sent "<<counter_sent<<" and received "<<counter_received<<" and removed "<<counter_removed<<endl;
    cout<<"done passing"<<endl;
}
```

I only posted some of the code (so ignore the fact that some variables may appear to be undefined, as they are in a portion of the code I didn't post)

When I run the code (on the machine in which it fails), I get `done passing` but not `done passing particles`

I am lost as to what could possibly cause a segmentation fault between the end of the called function and the next line in the calling function and why it would happen on one machine and not another.

Comment: It sometimes happens when you have a `non-void` return type but you forget to return along a particular path. `clang` and `MSVC` complains on such errors but sometimes `GCC` doesn't. In case you ___are___ using `GCC` make sure you have `-Wall` in place.

Comment: We really need to see more code. You're likely causing undefined behaviour elsewhere in your code.

Comment: I am using `GCC` and I am using `-Wall`. The function passing_particles is about 500 lines long, but I will post a portion of it. Not sure if it will make sense or not...

Comment: scratch that, I am using `intel 12.1`, it's a bit confusing since it is an mpi program. I thought it was built with `GCC`, but it's not.

Answer (score 5):

If you're crashing between the end of a function and the subsequent line in the caller, you're probably crashing in the destructor of a local variable.  You need to run the program in a debugger to find out which object's destructor is crashing.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of possibilities:

1. You actually are returning, but cout is buffered by the OS so you don't see "done passing particles" because the application crashes first.
2. You have some local class that has a destructor that is seg faulting.

Try running it in a debugger to find out where it is actually crashing.

Edit:

Since you've mentioned you're using gcc, add the -g flag and run it with gdb. Gdb will then tell you exactly where it's going wrong (probably a null dereference).

Comment: The `endl` after `cout` makes sure output is flushed.

Comment: @Hindol There is no guarantee that the operating system will flush when it gets a newline, just a high likelihood that that is the case.

Comment: `endl` is not same as newline. It is comparable to C's `fflush()`.

Comment: I was actually thinking more along the lines of transparent OS flushing. So I guess my suggestion to flush is a little silly.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone comes back to this later. I updated to the newest version of boost mpi(at the time), 1.50 and this issue went away. Not much of a solution, but it worked.